# If field exist must be true, but if not exist must be pass like true

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I would like to check if a field exist in pipeline `aggregate` (`existeTransformacion`) . If this field exist must be true to pass (`$match`) and if is false I need to exclude from my results, but if not exist must be pass. How can I achieve this?

```
 {
            //...more data
            "ubicacionActual": {
                "transformacion": {
                   "trabajando": true,
                }
            },
            //This field come from $project in this way 
            //$project: {existeTransformacion: '$ubicacionActual.transformacion.trabajando'}
            "existeTransformacion": true,
            "paso": 1
        },
```

So basically:

- If exist `existeTransformacion` and `existeTransformacion===true`
  must be showing.
- If exist `existeTransformacion` and `existeTransformacion===false`
  must be not showing.
- if not exist must be showing.

Comment: It's a bit confusing: You already have this field `existeTransformacion`? or you need to calculate it's value? `$match` is appliable only for pipeline step, not for `$project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$or` and `$exists` operators

```
{
  $match: {
    $or: [
      {
        "existeTransformacion": true
      },
      {
        "existeTransformacion": {
          $exists: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xMqzT09xO8q)